# How to transform second polyline according to first polyline

Tags: c#, .net, autocad

I have 2 polylines: I have drawn the first polyline and extruded a region along this polyline.

After this, I need to process the second polyline to start at the correct position (moving the 2nd polyline start point to 1st polyline end point) but I can't transform second polyline to the correct direction.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use the command **3Drotate** or **rotate3D** (each has a little different way of selecting parameters) to rotate the second polyline along the y axis
or change the UCS to XZ plane and use **rotate**

another option is to use **mirror3D** instead of copying the polyline

edit: now i noticed, you tagged your question .NET and C#, so the right answer should be **TransformBy** method used on the polyline object